# css disable / null row without using display: none

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a series of divs that I am using to display data in a tabular fashion.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

But this is what I am trying to change the css to achieve:

[image]

I cannot change the HTML (namely the <.div.class='row'.> must stay in place) because the HTML framework is used for other different css styles.

I am having trouble adapting the css as I am not sure how to apply the css to the <.div.class='row'.> so that the display I require is achieved (if I delete the row div, the display I want is achieved). I have tried many things but nothing works for me.

**Is it possible to change the class row so that I can achieve the desired display (shown above)?** Or should I implement separate HTML code to cover this issue? I thought I should ask as it would save a lot of time and effort - just not sure if it can be done.

This is my HTML code:

```css
    .wrapper{
        border-spacing: 1px 1px;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .row{
        display: table-row;
    }
    
    .heading {
        display: table-cell; 
        width: 18%; 
        background-color: #000; 
        color: #fff; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    .content {
        display: table-cell; 
        width: 98%; 
        padding: 2px; 
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="heading">SUMMARY</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">
                This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details.<br /><br />
                This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can make .row float:left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6vote8pz/1/

You need to add display:table-cell to the row:

```
.row{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: gopalraju, thanks, that does display the div's side-by-side, but how do I make the left div the same height as the right div. I have used your code, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

use this for element with row class

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0uvy2Lj/) just mess around with the width

Comment: One could additionally use `first-child` and `last-child` to target both rows separately for the widths: https://jsfiddle.net/f0uvy2Lj/1/

Comment: Laurens, appreciate the response, but I need the divs side-by-side not one on top of another.

Comment: They are side-by-side

Comment: @user3354539 If you adjust the width correctly, they are side by side. In the exact fiddle, however, margins prevent that. Reduce the `50%` width to something smaller in his fiddle and you'll be fine. Or take a look at my fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. You just need to arrange your html code the way it should be. You can check here https://jsfiddle.net/h1e2nvb7/ or below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="heading">SUMMARY</div>
    <div class="content">
        This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details.<br /><br />
        This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details. This is a test of the summary details.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Quote from the question "I cannot change the HTML".

Comment: @Sirko true, but the OP also says "Or should I implement separate HTML code to cover this issue?".

Answer (score 0):

simply try css grid property

[css grid](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_grid-columns.asp)

or 
put

```
.row{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```